# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported http status 405

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-post, http-status-code-405

I am making a post to the controller and this is the form with the action parameter value

```
<div class="form-group">    
                          <form action="searchT">
                              <label class=" control-label col-sm-2">No</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-4"> <input class="form-control" type='text' name='searchName' id='searchName'/> </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-4"><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='Validate'/></div>
                          </form>
                         </div>
```

this is the controller code that does the fetching of values from the database when a button is clicked

```
@RequestMapping("searchT")
    public ModelAndView searchTOE(@RequestParam("searchName") String searchName) {  
        logger.info("Searching the T: "+searchName);
        List<TOE> tinList = TOEService.getAllTins(searchName);
        return new ModelAndView("serviceDescription", "tList", tList);      
    }
```

when I click on the submit I get this error

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not
supported

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource
```

.

Comment: As fas as i know the default Requst method is GET so you have to specify the request type in your controller

Comment: So why is it telling the request method post is not supported

Comment: is it not supposed to be the request method GET is not supported?

Comment: if that is the issue

Comment: try adding method="GET" in your form , hopefully this will work. `<form action="searchT" method="GET">`

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestMapping("searchT")`

Default method type is `GET`. You should mention the method type as `POST` in `RequestMapping`.